# how have i to paralerize a task

Tags: java, fork-join

I have 3 servers(debian based) in my local network. On one of them runs an app, which requires lots of CPU Power. Lets say its on server1, is it possible to provide CPU Power of Server2 and Server3 to Server1?

If not, I'm thinking about programming java client-server app.

It will be a client app on server1 and 2 server apps on server2,3. I use Fork-join Framework on all of them and will be sending a part of a given task from server1 to server2 and server3. They will compute the tasks and send the results back to the server1. Is it so right idea or isnt??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. You could consider using existing, proven and optimized distributed computing platforms for Java.
Two that come to mind, both open source:

Apache Ignite: ignite.apache.org

HazelCast: http://hazelcast.org/

They're both easy to get started with and they were built with resource management in mind.